# Why is $\{Y>Y'\}$ $\mathcal{F}-$measurable?

Tags: probability-theory

If $Y,Y'$ are $\mathcal{F}-$measurable, why is $\{Y>Y'\}$ $\mathcal{F}-$measurable?

I thought of doing something similar to $\{Y>Y'\}=\bigcup_{y'}(\{Y'=y'\}\cap\{Y>y'\})$, however, we can't be sure that this will be a countable union...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because $$ \{ Y>Y' \} = \{ Y-Y' >0\}$$ and the sum of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Of course! thanks ;)

Comment: Which boils down to $\displaystyle \{ Y > Y' \} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \big[ \{ Y > q \} \cap \{ q > Y' \} \big].$$

Comment: @Adayah why can you say that?

Comment: Do you mean why $Y > Y' \iff (\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}) \, Y > q > Y'$ ?

Comment: @Adayah Thanks ;)